# Strange class behaviour when used inside a Qt app

Tags: c++, qt

I've a simple class with these, also simple, constructors:

```
audio::audio() {
    channels = NULL;
    nChannels = 0;  
}

audio::audio(const char* filename) {
    audio();
    getFromFile(filename);
}
```

(Before it was `audio():channels(NULL), nChannles(0), loaded(false){...`, I'll say later why this changed...). The function `getFromFile` starts like this:

```
void audio::getFromFile(const char* filename) {
    baseUtils::dynVec<float> *chans;
    if (channels != NULL)
        deleteChannels();
    sox_format_t *in;
    sox_sample_t buff[AUDIO_CLASS_READ_SAMPLES];
    sox_sample_t sample;
...
```

As you can see, it checks if `loaded` is true and if it is runs some `delete`(s) on internal buffers. Of course, as you can see from the constructor, at first run `loaded` is false, then the 2nd constructor will call the first constructor and then have `loaded = false`.

If I run this class in a simple command line app, everything runs fine. But if I put it in a Qt application, precisely in a slot that does this:

```
void buttonPushed() {

        QString s = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();
        std::cout << "file choosen: " << s.toStdString() << "\n";
        sndfile = s.toStdString();
        if (aud == NULL){
            aud = new audio(sndfile.c_str());
            ui.widget->setAudio(aud);
            ui.widget->update();
        }
[...]
```

it will have `channels != NULL` (after invoking the 2nd constructor) and try to delete a pointer that is not assigned (resulting in a segmentation fault). Using GDB I found that `channels` is set to some strange value, and `nChannels` too... This smells like a race condition, but apparently doesn't seem to be the case. I put a check in the slot to see if `aud != NULL`, to avoid this. Do you have any ideas? Why is it happening? I tried to use Valgrind and it says that at `channels != NULL` I am trying to do a conditional jump with an uninitialized value! How can it be? What about the constructors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is in the `audio::audio(const char* filename)`  constructor. The first statement is `audio();` which I believe you are trying to call the default constructor. However, C++ doesn't allow one ctor to call another one. So you have uninitialized pointers. If you want to do something like this, write a private method called `init()` and call it from both the constructors. `audio();` statement creates a temporary (unnamed) audio object using the default ctor which is destroyed immediately after this statement. So the object you are accessing after this is a different object which has uninitialized pointers.

Comment: audio(); creates an object, but since you aren't naming it, you have no way to access it later.

Comment: `audio()` creates a new temporary `audio` object, not storing it in any variable (it then immediately gets destroyed again).

Comment: You can either use the init() method described above, or you can subclass audio, provide it a new constructor, and call the old one from the new one like this: childClass() : baseClass(){//ctor logic here} ....i think i would prefer the init() method.

Comment: Thank you all. sorry I've been using Java for a long time. Still some glitches